# Creating dll of python script with functions using OpenCV functions

Tags: python, c++, opencv, dll, labview

I created a dll file using Visual Studio 2010 for python script which contains only python function and used it in labview using "Call Library Function Node" VI available in labview. It works fine.
Followed the same procedure in the link below
"http://www.originlab.com/doc/OriginC/guide/Access-Python-via-External-DLL"

But if I am creating a dll file for python script containing opencv and python functions labview throws memory issue. 
Do I need to add some other dependencies of OpenCV as well. If so, then what should be added?